# When using custom key for autocompletion in CodeMirror, how to print the key that has been pressed?

Tags: codemirror

I am currently using the following code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     editorftl = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codeftl"), {
         mode: "text/ftl",
         lineNumbers : "true",
         extraKeys: {"'<'": function (cm){CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.ftl);}},
     });
});
```

I want to print the "<" key on the textarea and also display the autocomplete options. 
Is it possible?

Comment: use `&gt;` for `>` and `&lt;` for `<` this is markup code to render this symbols.

Comment: Should I use them in the script itself or rather on the html page?

Comment: Well its not working :( .

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: Post some sample code using jsfiddle.net site so experts can help you better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html for a demo that does autocompletion like that.

Comment: Thanks to you again for helping me out.